# Add Tag to post after publishing

Tags: actions, tags, save-post

I want to add a specific tag to posts being published, I tried the following code and searched for answers here but it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea why?

```
function tag_to_published_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
// check if just an update
if ( $update ) {
    return;
}
//add tag
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, 'tag-to-be-added', true ); 
} 
add_action( 'save_post', 'tag_to_published_post', 10, 3);
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: On my wp this code works. It adds tag `'tag-to-be-added' even before post save this tag is assigned to post.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thanks, you're right, seems like it works from the backend. I failed to mention that I tried using it with a front end post submission (the Plugin). Is there any way to make it work under these circumstances?